# HighchartsReact adding line between 2 dots while hovering using Stacked area

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts, stacked-area-chart

I want to add a line that connects between the 2 dots on the graph while hovering.
currently it looks like this:
[image]

and I want it to look like this:

[image]

my current connfig:

```
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false,
                    symbol: "circle",
                    radius: 2,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            enabled: true,
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            area: {
                stacking: 'normal', //Stacked area
                lineColor: '#666666',
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    lineColor: '#666666'
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: What determines which two points the line should be drawn between? The line also appears to go from the topmost point all the way down to the X-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by adding `xAxis.crosshair`:

**Example config:**

```
  xAxis: {
    crosshair: {
      width: 3,
      color: 'grey'
    }
  },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/abspu5e1/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.crosshair